# More detailed comparison within a line

Tags: vimdiff

I use `vimdiff` to inspect differences between files, and some times it misses out a bit. for example, if I have the following two files:

```
//a.c
printf("Hello\n");
```

and:

```
//b.c
int i = printf("hello\n") + 3;
```

showing them in `vimdiff` gives:

[image]

What I will want to see is that in b.c the `h` is not capitalized.

Is there a way to tell vimdiff to compare (in that line) just part of it (I mean, ignore the `int i =` and the `+ 3`)?

Comment: The [diffchar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4932) plugin is probably what you need but I have zero experience with it. Maybe someone with experience using it can give a good, detailed answer (or maybe an alternative).

Answer (score 21):

I don't think this can be done by Vim itself. From [`:h view-diffs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/diff.txt.html#view-diffs) (emphasis mine):

```
hl-DiffText   DiffText        Changed text inside a Changed line.  Vim
                                finds the first character that is different,
                                and the last character that is different
                                (searching from the end of the line).  The
                                text in between is highlighted.  This means
                                that parts in the middle that are still the
                                same are highlighted anyway.  Only "iwhite" of
                                'diffopt' is used here.
```

---

[Tokoyami's suggestion](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/more-detailed-comparison-within-a-line#comment571_499) takes us one step closer. Install [`diffchar`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4932) ([Github link](https://github.com/rickhowe/diffchar.vim) for those using a plugin autoloader). Since v4.7, with the plugin enabled, Vim automatically shows more exact differences:

[image]

- You can press <kbd>F7</kbd> (the default keymap) to toggle between the usual and the plugin. Reassign with:

  ```
  nmap <silent> <key> <Plug>ToggleDiffCharAllLines
  ```

  replacing `<key>` with an appropriate key code.
- You can use more colors:

  ```
  let g:DiffColors=100
  ```

Comment: +1 but "one step closer" seems overly conservative to me. Diffchar *totally* solves this issue IMO.

Comment: @Sparhawk well, it doesn't ignore the common elements in a line (OP wants just the changes highlighted)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. Aren't the common elements ignored in this example (e.g. `printf` and `ello`)?

Comment: @Sparhawk in this example, yes. But with more complex changes, it quickly becomes messy.

Comment: Ah okay, so it's a bit buggy then… thanks for the information.