# Word level diffs in Vim

Tags: vimdiff

As far as I understand the default `vimdiff` is doing only line-wise diffs. However sometimes is useful to do word level diff, especially for text files like Markdown, LaTeX etc. There are some tools like `wdiff` or `dwdiff` which do the diff in word level.

Is it possible to use them in Vim to compare side-by-side two text files?

Comment: I don't know if it can restrict to words, but checkout the plugin mentioned in http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/499/more-detailed-comparison-within-a-line

Comment: Huh. Apparently it can. Add `let g:DiffUnit="Word1"` and it does word-level highlighting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution, as suggested by [muru](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/205/muru) (thanks), is to use the [diffchar.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4932) plugin and setting the `let g:DiffUnit="Word1"`. This plugin should be used in the standard `vimdiff` session.